# Running async task end up locking up Razor page (ASP.NET "Web Pages", not ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages, async-await

There are 3 different ASP.NET technology which are WebForm, MVC and Web Pages (Razor & non-MVC).

I had figure out how to use async Task in WebForm but not in Web Pages.  I noticed the async task get stuck, waiting for it to finish - meaning the razor page (or the class) is not async.  So, what do you guys do to make this work on ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor & non-MVC).

```
//Integration Project (Photo Server Project [DLL])
namespace BIO.Dealer.Integration.PhotoServer
{
    //Constructor
    public VehiclePhotoManager(string username, string password, string template)
    {
        _client = new PhotoServerClient(username, password, template);
    }
    //Function
    public async Task<string[]> GetPhotoUrlsAsync(string vin, string size)
    {
        var listResponse = await _client.ListAsync(vin);

        return listResponse.Photos.ToArray();
    }
}

//Foo class (This is from Web Application Project)
namespace BIO.WebApp.Testcase.Infrastructure
{
    public class foo
    {
        //Function
        public string[] fooToo()
        {
            var managerVehiclePhoto = new VehiclePhotoManager("username","password","template");
            string[] photoServerUrls = managerVehiclePhoto.GetPhotoUrlAsync("12345678901234567","medium").Result;
            return photoServerUrls;
        }
    }
}

//Razor testcase webpage  (This is from Web Application Project)
@using BIO.WebApp.Testcase.Infrastructure

foo fooMe = new foo();
string[] photoUrls = fooMe.FooToo();
```

When you load the razor webpage that instanstance the foo class and call the FooToo function.  As you go deeper to a function in the PhotoServer project, it get stuck there waiting cuz it seems the Razor webpage does not specify the async/await script but razor webpage does not recognize those function.  So, I moved it to a infrastructure class with no such luck.

Can anyone help me out?  Thanks.

Comment: We're on the same quest :) [This post from Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) was my moment of zen. Hth...

Comment: @EdSF - You're onto something here.  Good Idea.  I end up creating a static class with list of functions, in each of them function making a .NET framework HttpClient call to Async Web Generic Handler (*.ashx) and return the result.   Not pretty, suck that I keep getting lost in the daisy chaining script and kept hopping around with the source code to get to the right function.   I haven't yet learn how to master the Web API Controller because I kept getting the webpage not found error (even with the right url path).  :-(